# Why is my drawn image flickering on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

The full source is on Github at [this address](https://github.com/gingerdeadshot/Zerfall-Java).

I have a JPanel in which I draw a background and the player sprite. The logic and the repainting are on separate timescales. Here is the relevant code:

```
static long logicSleep = (long) (1e9 / 120);
static long drawSleep = (long) (1e9 / 60);
static long startTime;
static long logicTime, drawTime;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while (keys[KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE] == false) {
        if (System.nanoTime() > logicTime + startTime) {
            player.logic();
            logicTime += logicSleep;
        }
        if (System.nanoTime() > drawTime + startTime) {
            sheet.repaint();
            drawTime += drawSleep;
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

As such, the logic runs every 1/120 seconds, and the drawing runs every 1/60 seconds. This works as intended. However, the image flickers every so often. It's not screen tearing, as I have Java 8 and my monitor refreshes at 60 Hz (not to mention how double buffering on jpanels is enabled by default). The flickering appears to be an abrupt change in position, although the actual position of the character on screen is only affected for about one single frame.

Here is my custom JPanel class:

```
static class Sheet extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
        super.paintComponent(g1);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
        g.translate((int) -(player.xPos + player.sprites[0].getWidth() / 2 - getWidth() / 2),
                (int) -(player.yPos + player.sprites[0].getHeight() / 2 - getHeight() / 2));
        g.drawImage(map, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(player.sprites[player.spriteNum], (int) player.xPos, (int) player.yPos, null);
        g.drawImage(foreground, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

I have managed to fix this, by changing the logic sleep to run every 1/180 seconds, but I am curious as to why this happens with the logic running at certain timescales. This also occurs with the logic updating every 1/240 seconds.

TL;DR: My sprite is flickering because of my logic tick and I don't know why.

Comment: use the method `setDoubleBuffered(true);` on your JPanel

Comment: @WalterM: no need to do that, and in fact that won't help, as JPanels are already double buffered by default, **but** are you drawing in paint and not paintComponent? You should be drawing in the latter (paintComponent) and not the former (paint). You're not showing us your graphics code so it's hard to help here. Best for you to create and show a [mcve].

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Edited for clarity.

Comment: @RealSkeptic That actually fixed the problem. Add an answer so that I can confirm it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main loop is a busy-wait loop. It keeps a CPU core completely busy doing comparisons (the `while` condition and the timing conditions). This wastes CPU, makes your system less responsive, and is generally not recommended. This in itself may have an effect on the scheduling of other threads and cause the flicker.

Also, you have chosen update times that have a common denominator (that is, 60 and 180, 60 and 120 and so on). This means that there are cycles in which both conditions should be triggered. If your logic calculation is long, it means the repaint will be delayed by that much time. This could be another cause of the flicker.

The proper way to do periodical tasks is to use a `Timer` object. Since you have two different timing loops, and you need them to be independent, you should be using two separate `Timer` instances.

You generally have two choices for a `Timer` class:

- `javax.swing.Timer` - runs the scheduled operation in the Event Dispatch Thread. This is good for operations like `repaint()` and is permissible for short logic operations, and since all operation run in the same thread, will not require volatiles or other means of ensuring memory visibility.
- `java.util.Timer` (alternatively, `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`) - good for scheduling non-GUI, more complicated operations that you would not want to run on the EDT. If you use this, you should take care to update GUI component using `SwingUtility` methods and to use `volatile` or other means of making the changes in data visible to the EDT, as they will be running in a different thread.

Comment: I altered the program to use a java.util.Timer for the logic and a javax.swing.Timer for the repaint. Now the flickering is even worse. It was absolutely fine when both were swing timers.